# The resource cannot be found. Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new in MVC. I am trying to use a jquery ajax to call a webservice in view. But its not working because the url is not recognize in correct way.

This is my jquery part

```
var data = '{"Hint":' + $('#autocomplete').val().trim() + '}';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'MyService.asmx/GetNames',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (x,y,z) {
                alert(x.responseText);
            }
        });
```

and my asmx page is just like shown below

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetNames(string Hint) 
    {
        return "Hint";
    }
```

I've tried to change the url in different ways like shown below

- MyService.asmx/GetNames
- /MyService.asmx/GetNames
- ~/MyService.asmx/GetNames
- window.location.href+MyService.asmx/GetNames

Can you please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your method name is HelloWorld not GetNames!!

Comment: Sorry that mistake is happend when I post here. In my project I did it correctly and now I am updated my question also.

Comment: where is the location of the file MyService?

Comment: Its just under the project without any parent folder.

Comment: did you uncomment the line  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] at the top of webservices?

Comment: use the data like this var data = { "Hint": $('#autocomplete').val().trim() };

Comment: [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]  was commented. Now I've tried again after uncomment the line. Its not working ;(

Comment: also put [HttpPost] attribute above the method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89988/discussion-between-libin-c-jacob-and-anoop-joshi).

Comment: use `url: '/MyService.asmx/GetNames',` like this this may work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your service is an `asmx` service you need to write full name of serivce i.e `MyService.asmx` and you have written `MyService`. Change your url to

```
url: 'MyService.asmx/GetNames',
```